# Let jQuery display name of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu that I have nested in a header.php that is loaded on every different page of my website.

I'd like to display the name of the page the user is currently visiting using jQuery. The div that displays the name has a .menu_location_inner class assigned to it. I thought the code would look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu_location_inner").html('some code here')
});
```

How would I save the pagename in the DOM and complete the code above?

Comment: Where do you want to display the name of the page?

Comment: Where should the name of your page come from, the page's title tag?

Comment: Where the name should come from is also part of my question, I wont need it for any other purpose than to display it in the menu bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a custom message and not just whatever happens to be in your page's title tag (if it's even set), You could conditionally name a variable based on the url, like so...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var page1 = location.href.match("index.html");
  var page2 = location.href.match("contact.html");
  var page3 = location.href.match("feedback.html");

  if(location.href.match(page1)) {
    var thisPage = "You're on our main page!"
  }

 if(location.href.match(page2)) {
    var thisPage = "You're on our contact page!"
  }

 if(location.href.match(page3)) {
    var thisPage = "You're on our feedback page!"
  }

  $(".menu_location_inner").html(thisPage);

});
```

**EDIT:**
Also, using the jQuery HTML feature gives you some additional power to do things. This may be helpful as well, I changed the last part of the code snippet to demonstrate...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var page1 = location.href.match("index.html");
  var page2 = location.href.match("contact.html");
  var page3 = location.href.match("feedback.html");

  if(location.href.match(page1)) {
    var thisPage = "You're on our main page!"
  }

 if(location.href.match(page2)) {
    var thisPage = "You're on our contact page!"
  }

 if(location.href.match(page3)) {
    var thisPage = "You're on our feedback page!"
  }
  //You can wrap your answer in any tag you'd like
  //You also have the option to add ID's and/or classes here
  $(".menu_location_inner").html('<p class="myClass" id="myID">' + thisPage + '</p>');

});
```

Comment: Very intuitive and indeed a better solution than having connected to the page title

Comment: Thanks, glad to help!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what you want. It fetches the text from inside the `title` tag and writes it into the element with class `menu_location_inner`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pagename = $("title").text();
    $(".menu_location_inner").text(pagename);
});
```